# How do I define struct pointers and non-pointers (. and ->)?

Tags: arrays, c, xcode, pointers, struct

If my struct looks like:

```
struct contact {
    char* name;
    int number;
};
```

and one of the functions I'm writing looks like:

```
int find(struct contact* pb, int len, char* name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (strcmp(name, pb->name[i]) == 0) // pb[i].name is OK!
            return pb[i].number; // pb->number[i] ? - but number is not a pointer
.
.
.
```

If we will take a closer look at the function `find`, we can see that the following: `pb->name[i]` is like writing `pb[i].name` is the same.
But what about: `pb[i].number` ? I know that `number` is not a pointer, so how can I write it similair to: `pb[i].number` ? It can not be: `pb->number[i]`, right?

Comment: "*..., we can see that the following: `pb->name[i]` is like writing `pb[i].name` is the same.*" - Why do you think that? And why would you index `name`? It is just a pointer to no object yet.

Comment: `pb->name[i]` is like writing `pb[0].name[i]`; `pb[i].name` is the same as `(pb+i)->name`

Comment: Does `pb` point to an array of structures of `contact` in the caller?

Answer (score 1):

`pb->name[i]` is ***not*** the same as `pb[i].name`.

`pb->name[i]` tells the computer to:

- Look at the value stored in the variable `pb` (which is an address)
- Look at the struct which that address points to (`->`)
- Look at the `name` in that struct.
- Look at the `i`-th thing in the array which `name` points to.

i.e. it returns the `i`-th character in the first contact's name.

`pb[i].name` tells the computer to:

- Look at the value stored in the variable `pb` (which is an address)
- Look at the `i`-th struct in the array which that address points to
- Look at the `name` in that struct.

i.e. it returns the address of the `i`-th contact's name.

`pb->number[i]` makes no sense because `number` isn't an array. You're asking for the `i`-th thing from the first contact's number, but the number isn't an array or a pointer to one.

`pb->name[i]` is also *wrong* but it makes sense. You're asking the computer for something which isn't the thing you want, but at least it's a thing which is possible, so the computer does it anyway.

Comment: You should note that we still got no proof if `name` points to something. Nor where it points to exactly (we don't know whether it really points to an array of `char`). So you should treat that as fundamental issue IMHO.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Do you demand proof of that from every question which involves pointers?

Comment: OP has fundamental issues in understanding pointers and arrays. Very likely, there is a mistake there too. So, in such a case, Yes. At least an answerer should note it somewhere and show doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is *exactly equivalent* to `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, compute the address of the `i`'th *object* following that address and dereference the result.

This means that the expression `*pb` is equivalent to `*(pb + 0)`, which is equivalent to `pb[0]`.  The subscript operation implicitly dereferences `pb`, so the type of the expression `pb[i]` is `struct contact`.

You use the `.` operator when the operand is a `struct` or `union` type, and the `->` operator when the operand is a *pointer* to a `struct` or `union` type.

Since the expression `pb[i]` has type `struct contact`, you'd use the `.` operator to access both the `name` and `number` members:

```
if ( !strcmp( name, pb[i].name ) ) 
  return pb[i].number;
```

`pb->name[i]` is *not* the same as `pb[i].name`, and as used in your code will lead to a runtime error.  You're not referencing the `i`'th `name` in your `pb` array - instead, you're referencing the `i`'th *character* in the `name` member of `pb[0]`.  You're passing that *character* value to `strcmp`, which expects an *address* value of type `char *`.  It's very unlikely that any regular character value is also a valid address, so you will almost certainly see a runtime error there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to directly answer this question I would suggest to use (*pb).number